# returning a db query unto a readable assoc array for json_encode?

Tags: php, ajax, associative-array

I am using `ajax` to pull some data from a `PHP` script I created. The `PHP` script queries the database for user information and comment information. There will be a lot of comments and I am trying to figure out how to return `3` records `(LIMIT 3)` - this is what I have:

```
foreach($results->fetch_assoc() as $key => $db_value) {
    //$array[$key] = $db_value;
    print_r($results->fetch_assoc());
}
```

`$results->fetch_assoc()` returns a single record set. I was messing around and couldn't figure it out.

What I am trying to do is have 3 arrays returned to the `HTML` doc via json_encode so that I can read it and display it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$data = array();

while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
   $data[] = $row; // stuff new row onto end of array
}

echo json_encode($data);
```